# Moodle 3.3 error parameters invalid Web Service

Tags: php, moodle

I'm implementing a moodle web service on localhost.
I followed all the steps to register the service, and I have the token to make the corresponding calls.
I have used the template for REST PHP by Jerome Mouneyrac (https://github.com/moodlehq/sample-ws-clients/blob/master/PHP-REST/client.php).

My code:

```
    $token = '60d4aef82f787b7a0c8499a648a6a919';
$domainname = 'http://localhost/moodle';

$functionname = 'core_user_create_users';
$restformat = 'json';
$user1 = new stdClass();
$user1->username = 'testo';
$user1->password = 'Password_2015';
$user1->createpassword = 0;
$user1->firstname = 'testfirstname1';
$user1->lastname = 'testlastname1';
$user1->email = 'muletssss@gmail.com';
$user1->auth = 'manual';
$user1->idnumber = '';//'testidnumber1';
$user1->lang = 'es';
$user1->theme = "standard";
$user1->timezone = '-12.5';
$user1->mailformat = 0;
$user1->description = 'Hello World!';
$user1->city = 'testcity1';
$user1->country = 'au';
$users = array($user1);//, $user2);
$params = array('users' => $users);
$serverurl = $domainname . '/webservice/rest/server.php'. '?wstoken=' . $token . '&wsfunction='.$functionname;
require_once('./curl.php');
$curl = new curl;
$restformat = ($restformat == 'json')?'&moodlewsrestformat=' . $restformat:'';
$resp = $curl->post($serverurl . $restformat, $params);
print_r($resp);
```

If I execute it returns this response

```
{"exception":"invalid_parameter_exception","errorcode":"invalidparameter","message":"Detectado valor de par\u00e1metro no v\u00e1lido","debuginfo":"users => Detectado valor de par\u00e1metro no v\u00e1lido: theme => Detectado valor de par\u00e1metro no v\u00e1lido: Invalid external api parameter: the value is \"standard\", the server was expecting \"theme\" type"}
```

The API documentation says that the value is string and standard default, so I comment this line because it is optional. And returns

```
{"exception":"moodle_exception","errorcode":"forcepasswordchangenotice","message":"error\/forcepasswordchangenotice"}
```

Does anyone know what I can do to work correctly, any solution?

Comment: I already found the solution, thanks for nothing

Comment: Whats the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue, I have solved it. The issue was that the user that I was using for the web services **had force password reset checked** while creation. I had not logged in once the user was created and was only using it for the Webservice. Hence I was this error was showing up. I unchecked force password reset from my admin account and it was solved.